# Probability that a prankster gets exposed.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

Is my solution correct?

There are 5 emergency operations centers with 4 phone numbers each. A teen has all their numbers and starts pranking. He chooses a random phone number but never calls the same number twice. Once he calls a number, the whole center becomes aware of him so calling the same operations center twice (two numbers of the same center) gets him caught.
What is the probability of him not getting caught after 3 calls?
What is the probability that he gets caught on his 3rd call?

5 centers have 4 numbers each, so 20 numbers in total. Since he has to make 3 calls, there are 20 * 19 * 18 = 6840 different ways of doing so. On his first call, all 20 numbers are available. On his second call, only 16 numbers are available if he doesn't want to get caught because each station has 4 numbers, so calling a station crosses out not 1 but 4 numbers. On his third call, only 12 numbers are available. Thus, he can call 20 * 16 * 12 = 3840 different ways without getting caught and so the probability is 3840 / 6840 = 32 / 57.

After 2 calls, he would've had called 2 centers (assuming that he doesn't get caught on the second call). 2 numbers would be no longer available at all since he never calls the same number twice, so there's 18 of them left. Calling 2 centers means that he would be exposed if he called either of them, meaning that calling 8 numbers would get him exposed. Since he has called 2 numbers already, calling only 6 of them could get him exposed. 3 centers remain untouched so the remaining 12 phone numbers don't change much. Thus, the probability of him getting caught is 6 / 18 = 1 / 3.

Is this good?

Comment: Yes. This all seems correct. The formatting is a little confusing though, so I might have missed something!

Comment: Your first answer is correct, but the second one isn't. When calculating the probability that he gets caught on the third call, you have to include the probabilities of him not getting caught on the first two calls. What you calculated is the conditional probability that he gets gets caught on the third call **given** that he doesn't get caught on the first two.

Answer (score 1):

- Probability not caught after one call: $\frac{20}{20} = 1$.
- Probability not caught after two calls: $\frac{20}{20}\times \frac{16}{19}  = \frac{16}{19} $.
- Probability not caught after three calls: $\frac{20}{20}\times \frac{16}{19}\times \frac{12}{18}  = \frac{32}{57}$ which is what you have
- Probability caught after exactly three calls: $\frac{20}{20}\times \frac{16}{19} \times \frac{6}{18}  = \frac{16}{57}$ which is not what you have

Your $\frac{6}{18}=\frac13$ is the conditional probability of being caught on the third call given he was not caught earlier.  But I think that is not what the question asks for.